# Show that if $n$ is composite, then $\phi(n) \leq n-\sqrt{n}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Please help me showing this:

> If $n$ is composite, then $\phi(n) \leq n-\sqrt{n}$.

I failed to proceed from the definition of Euler function $\phi(n)$. First of all if $n$ is composite, then it means that it can be written as a product of prime numbers that are unique. So that is what I know so far and I don't know how to proceed from that point.

Comment: Let p be the smallest prime dividing n, and see how many integers less than n that p forces not to be relatively prime to n.

Comment: I have not got your argument well.Can you please ellaborate more - John Brevik

Comment: Do an example -- say 21. The smallest prime dividing that is 3, and now any multiple of 3 is not relatively prime to 21. So just based on that 3, and not thinking of 7 at all, how far down have we cut the value of phi(21)?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896920/upper-bound-for-eulers-totient-function-on-composite-numbers

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**(one of my best solutions):

1. If we can write $n=ab$ with $a$ and $b$ are coprime  $\varphi(n)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ and $\varphi(a)\leq a-1$ and $\varphi(b)\leq b-1$ and conclude that $$\varphi(n)\leq ab-a-b+1\leq ab-\sqrt{ab}$$
2. If we cannot write $n=ab$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime then $n=p^k$ for som $k$ and $p$ a prime but in this case:
   $$\varphi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}\leq p^k-p^{\frac{k}{2}} $$
   because $k> 1$

Comment: φ(n)≤ab−a−b+1≤ab−√ab  How does the square root come in?I have failed to figure out how it comes about

Comment: $2\sqrt{ab}\leq \sqrt{a}^2+ \sqrt{b}^2=a+b$ but $\sqrt{ab}\geq 1$ so $\sqrt{ab}\leq a+b-\sqrt{ab}\leq a+b-1$ hence: $$ab-a-b+1\leq ab-\sqrt{ab} $$ and this not classic like i said it's just my favorite proof.

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach @Elaqqad used:

---

> Corollary:
>
> $$(\forall\;\text{prime}\;p)(\forall n\in\Bbb N) p\mid n\implies p\le\sqrt{n}$$

---

> Proposition:
>
> Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, then:
> $$\begin{aligned}\varphi(n)&=\prod_{i=1}^k\varphi\left(p_i^{\alpha_i}\right)\\&=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{\alpha_i}\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)\\&=n\left(1-\frac1{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac1{p_2}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)<n,\quad\alpha_i\in\Bbb N\;\forall\; i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}\end{aligned}$$

One argument is:
$$1-\frac1{p_i}<1\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$$
One can also use:
$$n=\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)$$

---

Let $p$ be the least prime factor of composite $n\in\Bbb N$ $($so we could get the maximum $\frac1{p_i}$$)$.
$$\varphi(n)\le n\left(1-\frac1p\right)\leq n\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)= n-\sqrt{n}$$
$$\text{Q.E.D.}$$