# euler totient approximation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

I want to find an approximation of Euler's totient.

It`s for product n of two prime number a and b

This is what I have actually:
\begin{array}{}
n = a.b\\
\varphi(n) = a.b - a - b + 1\\
\varphi(n) \approx n - 2.\sqrt{n}+1
\end{array}
This work fine for small number, but with number up to 2**64, the error is small but not negligeable.

I want to scale to bigger number.

I search a better approximation or find an corrector term. Can you help me ?

Edit 1 : this post [Upper bound for Euler's totient function on composite numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/896920/1104393) show in this case (number with two prime factors) than my approximation is in reality an upper bound. After I read the book link by Will Jagy, I find this lower bound :

\begin{array}{}
\frac{n}{\phi(n)} > {\rm e}^\gamma \log \log n\\
\frac{\phi(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{{\rm e}^\gamma \log \log n}\\
\phi(n) > \frac{1}{{\rm e}^\gamma \log \log n} . n\\
\end{array}

It exist a lower bound more accurate for my case ?

Comment: There isn't going to be a nice smooth function of $n$ that approximates $\phi(n)$, which varies wildly with the factorization of $n$.

Comment: Hardy and Wright do such approximations, especially pages 267-268. Very small values for $\varphi(n)$  occur when $n$ is primorial. http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Nicolas_1983.pdf