Approximation of Euler's totient function and semiprime factorization
So, I was looking at a completely different problem when I came across this equation:
$$T(n) = n - \operatorname{numpot}(n) - \left\lfloor\sqrt n\right\rfloor$$
Where "$\operatorname{numpot}(n)$" is the number of numbers that can be rewritten as powers of other numbers until $n$ (like $9$, $36$, $27$, and several others).
This equation seems to estimate the Euler's totient for semiprimes well. The deviation from the true Euler's totient follows a very sharp negative increase, but I couldn't synthesize the pattern in order to add to the formula above.
For example,
$$11 \cdot 17 = 187$$
My totient function returns: $157$.
The real Totient is $160$. Difference of $-3$.
As you increase the value of the observed semiprime, this decrease increases slowly.
$$43\cdot47 = 2021$$
My totient function returns: $1923$
The actual Totient is $1932$. Difference of $-9$.
The larger the semiprime, the larger the deviation seems to be, but, but at some point in the sequence of semiprimes this deviation strangely inverts:
$$21649210732553009 \cdot 213715928938829 = 4626781182500032990459360886461$$
Deviation: $+17560919210166400$.
I used this website to calculate the true totients: https://www.dcode.fr/euler-totient
Notice that not knowing how to calculate the deviation makes my function useless for large semiprimes.
And my main question is, if any of you can fix my function, would that imply efficient factorization of large semiprimes? (if my function always got it right, for example).
My Python function that I use to calculate my "$\operatorname{numpot}(n)$", this disregards the number 1 as a power of other numbers:
def numPot(n):
#Calcule the number of numbers that can be rewritten as powers of 
#other numbers until 'n'.
    exponent = 2
    choosen = 2
    total = 0
    while (choosen > 1):
       left = 1
       right = floor(sqrt(n))
       hit_the_nail_in_the_head = False
    
       while ((abs(right - left) > 1) and (right > left)):
           middle = floor((right + left)/2)
        
           calculus = floor(pow(middle, exponent))

           if (calculus < n):
               left = middle
           else:
               if (calculus > n):
                   right = middle
               else:
                   choosen = middle
                   hit_the_nail_in_the_head = True
                   break
    
       if (not hit_the_nail_in_the_head):
           calculus = floor(pow(right, exponent))
        
           if (calculus > n):
               choosen = left
           else:
               choosen = right
    
       i = 2
       k = choosen - 1
    
       while (floor(pow(i, 2)) <= choosen):
           k = k - 1
           assistant = 3
           while (floor(pow(i, assistant)) <= choosen):
               assistant = assistant + 1
               k = k - 1
           i = i + 1
    
       total = total + k
       exponent = exponent + 1

return total


How does $n$ affect $numpots(n)?$ There are infinitely many numbers that powers of another number...

In particular, it would help in your code, as a definition of the function, if you used whole words for the variable names. As writtten, we are entirely guessing what they represent.

To the OP: I have edited the formatting of the post. If I inadvertently changed something that you don't want there, you may roll back the edit.

Your definition of numpot$(n)$ does not involve $n$.  Please edit to include a proper definition, along with some examples.

To the main question: factoring and computing the totient function for semiprimes are equivalent.

Sorry for the poorly explained code, I tried to fix it, the variables with single letters are counters (k, i, j), and "assistant" is a variable that I couldn't find a better name for. And as for the function $numpot(n)$, it returns the number of numbers equal or smaller than $n$ that can be rewritten as powers of other numbers. Like $36 = 6²$, $27 = 3³$, $49 = 7²$. $numpot(10) = 3$, $numpot(16) = 4$, for example.

Note that your $\mathrm{numpot}(n)$ grows asymptotically like $\sqrt{n}$.

Good observation Jakob, now it seems to me that my function $T$ is equivalent to the approximation in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797946/euler-totient-approximation

Correct. It means that for semiprimes $n = p q$, $T(n)$ will be close to $\phi(n)$ if $p$ and $q$ are of similar size (since then they're both about $\sqrt{n}$).
